# Table "API_REQUEST_SUMMARY" not found;

Tags: wso2

I am trying to collect statistics in wso2AM using wso2BAM. When the API request completes no errors are reporting and the pass through works.

However when I try to access the statistics I get the error Table "API_REQUEST_SUMMARY" not found; SQL Statement:
SELECT time, year,month,day FROM API_REQUEST_SUMMARY order by time ASC limit 1 [42102-140]

No errors in the BAM logs. The Hadoop job is running every few seconds with no errors

Suggestions on what to look at?

OS is Linux
AM is 1.4.0
BAM is 2.3.0
I followed the instructions here for combining the two:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Have you correctly configured the WSO2AM_STATS_DB inside both APIM and BAM? If you are using h2 connection you have to make sure that <BAM_HOME> is replaced with absolute path of BAM installation directory. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. Missing a / in part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same exception can be happen, if user forgot to Copy the file /statistics/API_Manager_Analytics.tbox to directory, /repository/deployment/server/bam-toolbox.

So in that case only APIMGTSTATS_DB.db will be created without any tables.

Thanks
Ajith.

Comment: Hi,
i have the same problem.
It not appears any error in console, but the tables API_xxx ,  not are on database.